# Datatables queries with charts

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts, datatable

I've one question that keeps bothering me for a while now. I was wondering if it is possible to stream data from datatables query to chart. Let me elaborate (I hope..) Let's say that I have datatable with "fruits" on the left side and on the right side I have chart with that same data from datatable that shows number and type of the fruit

Let's say something like this:
[image]

So, my question is this. Is it possible as I'm querying data in my datatable to show that same query in graph on the right side. (eg. I'm searching for "apples" and as my table filter only apple result I would like to show that same result on graph as well)

You don't need to provide any code but some direction, links or explanation will do just fine. Thank you

I just want to point out that I'm using PHP & MySQL. With Google and Morris chart library.

Here is example of Morris chart using PHP

```
<div id="tipLampe"></div>
<?php
   try {
       $db = connectPDO();
       $row = $db->prepare("SELECT tip_lampe,count(tip_lampe) as broj FROM v_rasvjeta GROUP BY tip_lampe"); 
       $row->execute(); 
       $json_data=array();  
       foreach($row as $rec)  
       {  
           $json_array['label']=$rec['tip_lampe'];  
           $json_array['value']=$rec['broj'];  
           array_push($json_data,$json_array); 
       } 
   ?>
<script type="application/javascript">
   Morris.Donut({
     element: 'tipLampe',
     data: <?php echo json_encode($json_data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)?>
     });
</script>
<?php 
   closePDO($db);   
   } catch (PDOException $e) {
   showPDOErrors($e, $db);
   }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes** it can be achieved easily.

- Start with updating your datatable while you type *(just like autocomplete)*
- Query to database and bind that `result set` to `table` *(on left)*
- And apply that same `result set` on your `chart` as well *(on right)*

**Detailed info:**

- Create a route in php i.e. `/getlist?q=apple` to pass the user input as query parameter
- Return proper formatted data from server in `JSON` format
- Use ajax to call the route when user types in the `textbox`

Start it and come back if you get stuck. But atleast try!